# AFNetworking to REST API returns 401

Tags: ios, rest, afnetworking

I'm trying to use a REST API in my iOS app.  I know it works because I can make the login request once.  Every subsequent request fails with a 401 error.  Even if I delete the app from the simulator it still can't be called again until I change the simulator type to one that I haven't used before (i.e. iPad 2, iPhone6, etc.).  I can also use a service like https://www.hurl.it to make the same request with the same parameters as many times as I'd like.  I'm using `AFNetworking` and `AFHTTPRequestOperationManager`.  What am I doing wrong?

```
self.manager = [[AFHTTPRequestOperationManager alloc]initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.mydomain.com/"]];
[self.manager POST:@"services/json/user/login" parameters:@{@"username":@"USERNAME", @"password":@"PASSWORD"} success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    if (![responseObject isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) { return; }

    NSUserDefaults* defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSDictionary* json = responseObject;
    self.sessionName = json[@"session_name"];
    self.sessionId = json[@"sessionid"];
    [defaults setObject:self.sessionName forKey:@"SessionNameKey"];
    [defaults setObject:self.sessionId forKey:@"SessionIDKey"];

    if (completion) { completion(); }

} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Session request failed: %@", error.userInfo);
}];
```

Answer (score 1):

If first login called success, you should get some `access_token` which you use to send along with any subsequent calls.

Comment: You are correct.  And that access token works for all subsequent requests made in the same session.  But if I delete the app from the simulator and re-run it, the login code fails.

Comment: So login code only success once in the lifetime? That strange.

Comment: What service are you using? Is there any chance they implement this so wrong?

Comment: I thought it was strange as well.  I couldn't imagine what would be different about making the request in the iOS Simulator and hurl.it that a poorly implemented service would screw up.

Answer (score 1):

If API has basic authentication, then you need to pass credentials in HTTP header. 
To set credentials in header you can use following methods:

```
[self.manager.requestSerializer setAuthorizationHeaderFieldWithUsername:@"username" password:@"password"];
```

Comment: I get the same error passing the parameters this way.  I suspect this isn't correct though because the username and password are more accurately an App Name and App Token.

Comment: It depends on Webservices, Error code 401 means you are not authorised to access. If services has secured with basic authentication, by using given methods you can pass credentials.

Comment: That's true, but I've gotten my method to work multiple times.  It's the inability to call 'login' a second time that baffles me.

Answer (score 0):

(Unauthorised) 401 means you don't have access to the service. Make sure you are trying with correct credentials. Apparently there's nothing wrong with the code.

Answer (score 0):

Update for iOS9 with Swift 2.0 using Bearer authorization

I had the same problem, actually the `sessionManager.session.configuration.HTTPAdditionalHeaders` get overwritten by the `requestSerializer` on iOS9, which cause the 401 Access denied error.

Code that was working on iOS8, but not on iOS9:

```
sm.session.configuration.HTTPAdditionalHeaders = ["Authorization" : "Bearer \(token!)"]
```

New code for iOS9

```
sm.requestSerializer.setValue("Bearer \(token!)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
```